# The centralizer of a sylow subgroup of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $R \leq G$ such that $R$ is not normal in $G$. Let $R \leq N_G(R) \leq T$, where $T$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. If $T$ is abelian, then why $C_G(R)=T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is abelian and $R \subseteq T$, we clearly have $T \subseteq C_G(R)$. We have that $R$ is normal in $C_G(R)$, so $C_G(R)$ is not $G$. Because $T$ is a maximal subgroup, we have to have $C_G(R) = T$. Note that it was not important that $R$ was a Sylow subgroup. Every subgroup of $T$ which is not normal in $G$ has this property.

Comment: can you explain me why $T \subseteq C_G(R)$ please?

Comment: $T$ is abelian, so every element in $T$ commutes with every element in $T$. Since $R \subseteq T$, every element of $T$ commutes with every element of $R$, thus $T \subseteq C_G(R)$.